# Connect AWS Service from on-premise server by Site-to-site VPN instead of Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I have already setup Site-to-site vpn to connect on-premises server and aws vpc. It has connection between vpc app successfully.

However, the on-premise server would like to use sqs and secretsmanager too but the on-premise server doesnt have any internet connection. Is it possible to connect sqs and secret manager through site-to-site vpn? Or hv other solution? Thanks

Comment: What connectivity does it have? none? then you can't do anything. If it has a LAN connection, some component in that LAN must have internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

From high level you do need a conditional DNS forwarder on your on-prem and an inbound R53 DNS Resolver on AWS. You still need to create VPC Endpoints (Interface) and that should technically allow you access those services privately.